# Is there biblical evidence that the New Earth is our final destination?

Tags: biblical-basis, eschatology, new-earth

In [Revelation 21](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2021&version=NIV) we learn that following the resurrection Christians will inhabit a restored Earth called "The New Earth."

What biblical evidence exists that this is the final destination for humanity and not simply part of an "infinite finale" series of events in which there are cycles of history similar to the ones that we are currently experiencing?

Comment: [Long Discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9986/discussion-between-wax-eagle-and-thomas-jennings)

Comment: I'm tempted to say that this is still too broad. The Bible goes from creation *ex nihilo* to the New Earth, and there is nothing else. It would be easier to answer the question "What evidence is there that the New Earth is *not* our final destination?" -- the answer is None [Hell excepted, of course].

Comment: But can we, therefore, safely assume that the New Earth is the final destination? Would God hold back infomation or would Jesus have said otherwise if it were not so?

Comment: See John 14 v2.

Answer (score 1):

**The Bible Is *Sufficient Truth* but not *Exhaustive Truth***

The Bible reveals sufficient truth about *who we are* and *who God is* but does not reveal  exhaustive truth about everything we want to know. The Bible has sufficient truth to know about salvation that God prepared for us and how to live our life.

> *2 Timothy 3:16-17 (NIV)* All Scripture is God-breathed and is **useful for** teaching, rebuking, correcting and training in righteousness, so that the servant of God may be thoroughly equipped
>   **for every good work**.

Not everything is revealed to us. Not everything is recorded in the Bible. The Bible is not designed to contain every information about the past, the present or the future.

> *John 21:25 (NIV)* Jesus did many other things as well. If every one of
>   them were written down, I suppose that even the whole world would not
>   have room for the books that would be written.

That said, the Bible does not reveal everything about Heaven or what the future holds. Even the hour when Jesus Christ will return is concealed from Him.

**The New Earth simply happened to be the last thing that the Bible recorded**

The *New Earth* is certainly the last thing that the Bible mentioned regarding the destination of the chosen ones. This does not necessarily mean that it is the end of everything. There is also no evidence that it is not the end either. It is simply the last thing recorded in the Bible and there is nothing more to it. The Bible does not record any information about *cycles of history* unlike Hinduism which has [a cycle of four ages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yugas). What ever is not revealed to us, I believe we should not bother pondering about it.

Comment: Thanks! Disturbing though it is, this is a good well-researched answer!